# TelegramBot. В чём разница AbilityBot и TelegramLongPollingBot? Объясните

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Есть библиотека для Java, TelegramBots. Для создания бота. И вот есть два варианта создания:

```
public class MyBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    // TODO
}

@Override
public String getBotUsername() {
    // TODO
    return null;
}

@Override
public String getBotToken() {
    // TODO
    return null;
}
}
```

И второй

```
public class MyBot extends AbilityBot {

protected MyBot(String botToken, String botUsername, DefaultBotOptions botOptions) {
    super(botToken, botUsername, botOptions);
}

public int creatorId() {
    return 0;
}

public Ability pingPong() {
    return Ability
            .builder()
            .name("ping")
            .info("ping pong")
            .locality(ALL)
            .privacy(PUBLIC)
            .action(ctx -> silent.send("pong", ctx.chatId()))
            .build();
}

}
```

Т.е как видите разница в наследовании. Или TelegramLongPollingBot или AbilityBot. Так вот объясните мне, в чём у них разница? У автора библиотеки я не нашёл ответа на свой вопрос. Нашёл, что второй вариант поддерживает прокси,но почему тогда нет поддержки для TelegramLongPollingBot? Как тогда в случае наследования AbilityBot обрабатывать сообщения и остальное? Ведь нету

```
public void onUpdateReceived.
```

Answer (score 2):

Читать https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/blob/master/telegrambots-abilities/README.md

После внедрения моего пятого бота с использованием этого API у меня было это с количеством кода шаблона, который был необходим для каждой добавленной функции. Методы становились чрезмерно сложными, и читаемость стала подпунктом. Именно там начало формироваться понятие другого уровня абстракции (AbilityBot).

По поводу прокси, он поддерживается и в обоих версиях начиная с 3.6.1. В вашем наследуемом классе от TelegramLongPollingBot нужно добавить новый конструктор.

```
    public TelegramMessageBot(String botName, String token, DefaultBotOptions options) {
    super(options);
    this.botName = botName;
    this.token = token;
}
```

У меня сделано пока так:

```
            if (config.getBoolean("telegram.useproxy")){
            String proxyHost = config.getString("telegram.proxyhost");
            Integer proxyPort = config.getInteger("telegram.proxyport");
            String proxyUser = config.getString("telegram.proxyuser");
            String proxyPassword = config.getString("telegram.proxypassword");
            CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUser, proxyPassword));

            HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(proxyHost,proxyPort);

            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(httpHost).setAuthenticationEnabled(true).build();
            botOptions.setRequestConfig(requestConfig);
            botOptions.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
            botOptions.setHttpProxy(httpHost);
            telegramMessageBot = new TelegramMessageBot(botName, token, botOptions);
        } else {
            telegramMessageBot = new TelegramMessageBot(botName, token);
        }

        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(telegramMessageBot);

        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```